# how to display all content for the people table

Tags: users

How does one display all the data in the people table in a SQL or other statement? I would like to get a complete listing of the table(s).

Answer (score 1):

There is no table `{people}` in the database.  However, the way I understand this question, you want to display everything that is recorded about all user entities (i.e. you want the list of user entities that is shown under *People* in the admin interface expanded to include *all* the fields attached to such entities).

In that case, you can install the [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) project and enable the **Views** and **Views UI** modules (both part of the Views project). The recipe below assumes you're using Views 3 on Drupal 7. Older versions are different.

Navigate to *Home » Administration » Structure » Views* and click *Add a new view*. Give the view the name "Users", and select "Users" from the *Show* pull down menu.  Click *Save & Exit*.  This will give you a page view showing all users, but no fields.

Now, return to *Home » Administration » Structure » Views*, locate the view named "Users", and click *Edit*.

Next, locate the "Fields" widget, and click *Add*.  Filter on "User".  This will show *all* fields defined for the user entity (except `pass`), with a checkbox for each.  Check all boxes and click *Apply (all displays)*.  Now you've get to configure how to show each of the fields.  You can of course do a lot of fine tuning here, but I find it better to do that later, after the view is fully populated with fields. So just click *Apply (all displays)* to each of these.  AFAIK, this gives you access to *all* the fields in the user entity except `pass` (which holds the user's hashed password, and is excluded for security purposes).

After you've added all, there will be a preview at the bottom of the page.  At this stage, the listing will not be pretty, but you can fine-tune how this appears later, by editing the format of the view.

When done editing, remember to click *Save* (near top of screen) to save the view.

If your objective is to export this data, there are deveral modules let you export lists produced by Views. One of these is [Views Data Export](https://drupal.org/project/views_data_export).

Comment: How do I do that and (potentially) download it to a CSV or other file?

Comment: How do I edit the format of the view? And, by the way, Thank you very much.